# NSManagedObject stops receiving merged changes after obtainPermanentIDsForObjects

Tags: core-data

I have a hierarchy of managed object contexts, like so:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

...where A's parent is the persistent store. A and C use a private queue, and B uses the main queue. I've found that doesn't seem to matter, but I'll note it anyway.

So, here is the best way to replicate the issue:
- Context B creates an object. Because I need to reference this same object multiple places, I obtain a permanent object ID via obtainPermanentIDsForObjects. I then save.
- Context A inherits the change, saves it out to the permanent store. Context C sees the change notification and merges the changes in. All is good so far.
- I grab the object from context C and change one of the properties. I then save. Context A inherits the change and saves it to disk.

This is where it gets weird. Context B never sees the change. There is a change notification I intercept like so:

```
-(void)contextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [notification object];
    if(context!=_moc.parentContext)
        return;
    NSLog(@"Context %@ did save, merging into %@, info:\n%@", context, _moc, [notification userInfo]);
    [_moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

And I see the change go out, and seeing it merged in to context B. But the object I created in the first step never sees any changes.

I've traced this all back to one very specific thing. If I don't obtain a permanent object ID on the object in the very first step, the changes get merged back to the original object in context B just fine. But this leaves me without a reliable object ID to use in other contexts (as far as I know).

This seems like it could be a bug. I hope not. But for some reason when I obtain a permanent object ID it blocks changes from being merged back in from other contexts.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Any solutions?

(I know changes from context C are making it in to A, and A is saving them to disk. If I relaunch the app the changes are there from disk.)